# Swift CollectionView Reusable Cells Registering

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have a Problem with a CollectionView inside a `UIViewcontroller`.
I get my data from a JSON and in special conditions the cells don't seem to be reused properly, and I think there is something wrong with the way I've setup my Collectionview.

A overview:

My `MyCollectionViewCell.swift`:

```
import UIKit

class MyCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var bottomLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var topLabel: UILabel!

}
```

As you can see I have two labels in my Cell.
And Parts of my Viewcontroller:

```
import UIKit

private let reuseIdentifier = "colcel"

class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Register cell classes
        //collectionView.register(MyCollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

        //SOME JSON PARSING HAPPENS HERE

        collectionView.delegate = self
        collectionView.dataSource = self
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let colcel = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! MyCollectionViewCell

        colcel.contentView.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0
        colcel.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.darkGray.cgColor
        colcel.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 12, height: 4.0)
        colcel.layer.shadowRadius = 12.0
        colcel.layer.masksToBounds = false

        return colcel
    }
}
```

Now when I try to use for Example:

```
colcel.topLabel.text = "someText"
```

I get:

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

When I remove the `collectionview.register` in the `viewDidLoad()` it works.
Now is the question is my `register` action not neccesary or is it just wrong?

//edit.

My Cell REordering:

In the `viewDidLoad()` is this:

```
//Long Pressure for reordering
let longPressGesture = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.handleLongGesture))
self.collectionView.addGestureRecognizer(longPressGesture)
```

This is the corresponding function:

```
func handleLongGesture(gesture: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {

    switch(gesture.state) {

    case UIGestureRecognizerState.began:
        guard let selectedIndexPath = self.collectionView.indexPathForItem(at: gesture.location(in: self.collectionView)) else {
            break
        }
        collectionView.beginInteractiveMovementForItem(at: selectedIndexPath)
    case UIGestureRecognizerState.changed:
        collectionView.updateInteractiveMovementTargetPosition(gesture.location(in: gesture.view!))
    case UIGestureRecognizerState.ended:
        collectionView.endInteractiveMovement()
    default:
        collectionView.cancelInteractiveMovement()
    }
}
```

and I have this function:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                    moveItemAt sourceIndexPath: IndexPath,
                    to destinationIndexPath: IndexPath)
{
    // Update data model to reflect the change
    let temp = devArray[sourceIndexPath.row]
    devArray[sourceIndexPath.row] = devArray[destinationIndexPath.row]
    devArray[destinationIndexPath.row] = temp
}
```

when I run

```
self.collectionView.reloadData()
```

sometimes the positions jump

Comment: are you sure your topLabel is properly connected as iboutlet?

Comment: Check if "topLabel" outlet is connected properly.

Comment: I'm sure it is, when I remove the register it works and I see the connection in the storyboard

Comment: I think this is the answer, but wich way is better? Or has one way any disadvantages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have designed your storyboard with a prototype cell with the appropriate base class, you should not also `register` the class. The storyboard prototype cell does all of that for you.

The only time you manually register a class is when you are creating the cell programmatically. In that case, you should remove the prototype cell, but your custom class has to create the subviews itself and hook up the outlets (no longer `@IBOutlet` references) programmatically.

In terms of why you'd use prototype cells vs. programmatically creating the cells, it's just much easier to use prototype cells. You have to write less code. If you use cell prototypes, storyboards do all of this quite gracefully, so I see no benefit in going old-school and registering the class and programmatically creating the cells manually. It's just how we used to do it before we had prototype cells. But using storyboard vs programmatically created cells shouldn't affect the cell reuse logic.

You said:

> ... in special conditions the cells don't seem to be reused properly.

You should show us in what case the cells aren't reused. It's worth noting that when scrolling extremely quickly, cells aren't reused immediately after they scroll out of view. There's a little bit of lag before they're reused. If that's the scenario you're seeing that behavior, then, yes, I'm not surprised by that behavior. If that's not where you're seeing it not successfully dequeue/reuse cells, then share details regarding when and where you're seeing this behavior.

---

Regarding your separate reordering problem, the [`collectionView(_:moveItemAt:to:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uicollectionviewdatasource/1618064-collectionview) is swapping the source and the destination. But what you want is to `remove` and `insert`:

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, moveItemAt sourceIndexPath: IndexPath, to destinationIndexPath: IndexPath) {
    let value = devArray.remove(at: sourceIndexPath.item)
    devArray.insert(value, at: destinationIndexPath.item)
}
```

Because you're swapping, the one cell in question looks fine (so everything looks OK when you finish your drag), but all of the other cells in-between will be wrong. And you won't see that until you reload the collection view and/or scroll away and then back. By doing `remove` and `insert`, instead, the model should stay in sync.

Comment: I'ts a bit complicated but I'll try to explain: One Example: I have a function to reorder the cells in the collectionView, but sometimes when i reload the view some cells jump in their position.  Second example: When a value from the JSON I parse is Null und my guard Statement jumps in it displays a emty cell, but when I reload the view, I have the contents of another cell in this cell

Comment: ok I think the problem is my reordering function, the cells are not "jumping" they are rearranging, the array behind them is ordered wrong

Comment: Yeah, when you move from one cell to another, you want to insert the item at the destination, not swap it.

Answer (score 0):

Please check Custom Class on UICollectionViewCell property,
make sure the value is MyCollectionViewCell --> [ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m1V8Q.png)